# Boundary conditions for radial solution of gauged topological vortices

Tags: energy, boundary-conditions, vortex, solitons

I am following the book [*Topological Solitons*](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511617034) by Manton and Sutcliffe and I am struggling to understand a boundary condition they choose to find the radial solutions of gauged vortices with finite energy.

The energy of the vortices is given by

\begin{equation} \label{gauged_static_energy_functional}
    E = \int_{}^{}  \left(\frac{1}{2}\overline{D_i\phi}D_i\phi + \frac{1}{2}B^2 +U(\overline{\phi}\phi)\right)\,d^2x \
\end{equation}

It then assumes the ansatz:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \phi(\rho, \theta) &= \widetilde{\phi}(\rho)e^{iN\theta} \\
    A_{\rho}(\rho, \theta) &= A_{\rho}(\rho) \\
    A_{\theta}(\rho, \theta) &= A_{\theta}(\rho)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

And uses a gauge transformation to set $A_\rho=0$. The energy for fields of this form is then evaluated:

\begin{equation} \label{polar_gauged_static_energy_functional}
    E = \pi \int_{0}^{\infty}  \left[\frac{1}{\rho^2}\left(\frac{dA_{\theta}}{d\rho}\right)^2+\left(\frac{d\widetilde{\phi}}{d\rho}\right)^2+\frac{1}{\rho^2}(N-A_{\theta})^2\widetilde{\phi}^2+\frac{\lambda}{4}(\widetilde{\phi}^2-v^2)^2\right]\,\rho d\rho \
\end{equation}

Now it says that for this quantity to be finite, it requires $\lim_{\rho \to \infty} A_{\theta}(\rho) = N$ and $\lim_{\rho \to \infty} \widetilde{\phi}(\rho) = v$. I understand these are required so the energy density is $0$ at infinity. Then it requires $\widetilde{\phi}(0)=0$ which I understand is necessary so that the third term in the last expression doesn't diverge at the origin. However, I really don't know where the last condition, $A_{\theta}(0) = 0$, comes from.

Comment: So $\phi$ is some function, and $\theta$ and $\rho$ are polar coordinates? And what is $A_\theta$?

Comment: Yes, $\phi$ is a complex scalar field and $A_{\theta}$ is the theta-component of the electromagnetic potential. $\theta$ and $\rho$ are indeed polar coordinates.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible that, depending on the symmetry of the system (I do not know much about Solitons), $\vec{A}$ could be inversely proportional to $\rho$?